# jQuery Rearrange Divs with descending year with some transition effect

Tags: jquery, transition

I have the following divs and I want to rearrange divs on the basis of the year in them in descending order of year with some transition effect. How can I do this with jQuery ?

```
<div class="year">2002</div>
<div class="year">2003</div>
<div class="year">2001</div>
<div class="year">2004</div>
```

It should be rearrange like:

```
<div class="year">2001</div>
<div class="year">2002</div>
<div class="year">2003</div>
<div class="year">2004</div>
```

Comment: do you want jQuery to change the html or just animate the years into the correct order?

Comment: to arrange the year divs

Answer (score 0):

Could  try something like this:

```
var $yrs=$('.year'), $parent=$yrs.parent();

$yrs.detach().sort(function(a,b){    
    return a.textContent - b.textContent
}).hide();

$parent.append($yrs);
var delay=500;

$yrs.each(function(i){
     $yrs.eq(i).delay( i * delay).slideDown();           
});
```

Have no idea what sort of transition you have in mind

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2nxXf/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun one to play with.  Certainly, there are an infinite number of ways to do this and to show the animation.  Here's a sort animation that slides the current location down to zero height while sliding the new sorted location in to the proper height:

```
function animateSort(sel, time) {
    var items = [];
    $(sel).each(function() {
        items.push({elem: this, data: this.innerHTML});
    });

    items.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.data.localeCompare(b.data);
    });

    var cntr = 0;
    var insertLocation;
    function nextItem() {
        if (cntr < items.length) {
            var target = $(items[cntr++].elem);
            // insert a clone and let it slideup (to disappear)
            target.clone(false).insertAfter(target).slideUp(time, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            if (!insertLocation) {
                // if first one, make it first in the list
                target.prependTo(target.parent());
            } else {
                // insert after the last one we did
                target.insertAfter(insertLocation);
            }
            // hide, then slideDown (to reveal)
            target.hide().slideDown(time, nextItem);
            // set new insert location
            insertLocation = target;
        }
    }

    nextItem();
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TTEYL/

It works as follows:

1. Get a list of the items to sort.
2. Sort them according to their HTML content
3. For each item, make a clone.  Insert that clone at the location of the original so we have content to slideUp in the original location.
4. Move the current item we are sorting to it's proper sorted location in the DOM
5. Hide the current item (so we can slide it down)
6. Slide the clone up (so it disappears).
7. Slide the original (now in it's sorted location) slideUp (so it appears)
8. When animation done, remove the clone and start next sequence.